# How does devtools console know that a method of an object will cause mutation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, devtools

Let's say I've created an array `arr` through the console.

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,3,5]
```

Following will auto evaluate and show the result

```
a.slice()
```

[image]

Following will only evaluate when you invoke it. (Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
a.splice()
```

[image]

So, how does the console know that `splice` will cause mutation and `slice` will not.

Is there some kind of list of names of mutation causing functions under the hood?

Comment: How exactly it does that can only be answered by someone knowing the source code of the browser in question. The evaluation is most likely run through an interpreter to get the result. The interpreter could then be configured to throw an error if a mutation would occur instead of actually applying the mutation. 
This is just a guess though.

Comment: Why do you assume that lack of mutation is the sole criterion for display of return value previews?

Comment: @jsejcksn Because I've tested with many other methods of several objects. The only other "not very common" reason is computation timeout.